# What is .default in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I'm seeing a lot of errors related to .default not being a constructor, but I don't understand what default is in this context. I can't find any information on it in the documentation, [indeed there is a page on the default keyword on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/default) but it's not what I'm referring to.

The default I'm referring to is noted in error messages such as

> _Db2.default is not a constructor

Also, why is `_Db2` being referred to here? In the console I've tested to see if there is a _Db and there is. And `_Db === _Db2` is true. Why is this?

Note: We are using babel to transpile from es6 to commonjs

**EDIT:**

An example of importing

```
import Db from '../localstorage/db/Db';
const db = new Db(); //error is thrown here
```

Db looks a bit like this

```
import Realm from 'realm';

export default function Db() {
    this.realm = new Realm({
        schema: [Wallet, WalletAddress, WalletTransaction, Log, APIWallet, APITransaction, APIAccount, Configuration],
        path: config.db_path
    });
    logger(2, realm.path);
}

Db.prototype.doOneToMany = function(one, many) {..};

Db.prototype.query = function(model, filter) {..};

Db.prototype.insert = function(model, options) {..};

Db.prototype.del = function(model, obj) {..};

Db.prototype.update = function(obj, options) {..};

Db.prototype.write = function(func) {..};

Db.prototype.close = function() {..};
```

Comment: Maybe you could post some code? And, btw - `===` isn't a correct way to compare objects.

Comment: So, are you using a bundler tool like webpack?

Comment: @nicael `_Db === _Db2` is true, so the two objects are identical.

Comment: @Icepickle we are using the metro bundler. This is the react native environment

Comment: then check the path of your db, and check if it exports a default value something, it seems to me that either of the 2 is wrong

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to solve my issue, but this post is a question on what is default in this context since I can't find any information on this anywhere

Comment: `default` is (imo) the default exporter value, that gets bundled there, if you export a default value at least (the default you are referring to in your post, is the default branch of a switch statement, which has nothing to do with it). Note that default here is also a property and not a keyword (so theoretically, whatever has been assigned to it ;) ), maybe check how the bundler works. More info, on [babel](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es-modules.md#46-es-consuming-commonjs)

Comment: Or even a bit more info [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/)